# Issue with check times overlaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are two models:

```
# Table name: activities_people
#
#  activity_id :integer          not null
#  person_id   :integer          not null
#  date        :date             not null
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: activities
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name        :string(20)       not null
#  description :text
#  active      :boolean          not null
#  day_of_week :string(20)       not null
#  start_on    :time             not null
#  end_on      :time             not null
```

Relations:
activity.rb

```
has_many :activities_people
has_many :people, through: :activities_people
```

activity_people.rb

```
belongs_to :person
belongs_to :activity
```

I try to create validation that person can join to one activity taking place in specific date and time(start_on, end_on). If I will try sign up to another activity while before I joined to other exercises(same date, and times overlap) should throw error.
What I try:

```
  def check_join_client
    activities_date = person.activities_people.where('date = date', date: date)
    if activities_date.exists && person.activities.where('id IN (?)', activities_date)
  end
```

I don't know how to use create query(person.activities.where ...) to getting person activities related with activies_people. activities_date check if we joined to activities taking place in same date. Second I want get check start_on and end_on.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Easy way to do "where in" is to provide an array: i.e. `User.where(id: [1,2,3])`

Comment: @maxpleaner ok I understand, but how to check person.activities id(activity id not person) is inactivities_date result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to find the `activites_people` for a user that match a query by the date array and then raise an error unless an associated `activity` for those matched `activities_people`.

Your original code for `check_join_client` uses `if` incorrectly:

```
 def check_join_client
    activities_date = person.activities_people.where('date = date', date: date)
    if activities_date.exists && person.activities.where('id IN (?)', activities_date)
  end
```

To translate this to pseudocode, you're essentially saying:

```
result = query if result.condition_met?
```

However the `if` condition (the expression after the `if`) will be evaluated before you define `results`. It might be more clear if I show a correct approach:

result = query
  return result if result.condition_met?

Now to go back to your question about loading associated records, try something like this:

```
   activities_people_ids_matching_date = person.activities_people
                                               .where(date: self.date)
                                               .pluck(:id)
   # use pluck to get an array of ids because that's all that's needed here
   # not sure how you're getting the date variable, so I'm assuming self.date will work
   # I can use `.any?` to see if the ids list is not empty.
   condition_met = activities_people_ids_matching_date.any? &&\
                   person.activities
                         .where(activities_people_id: activities_people_ids_matching_date)
                         .any?
   condition_met ? true : raise(StandardError, "my error")
```

There surely is a way to get this done with one query instead of two, but it seems like where you're at with Ruby concepts it's more important to focus on syntax and core functionality than SQL optimization.

Comment: it's not all correctly, because now I cannot join to another activity in same date. We should check also time.E.G. First activity: 05.08.2016 8:00 - 9:00 Second activity: 05.08.2016 9:00 - 10:00 - correct. Second 05.08.2016 8:00 - 9:00,  05.08.2016 8:30 - 9:30 - incorrect.

Comment: not really clear ... are you trying to use a range of times in the query, i.e. 9 am through 10 am?

Comment: Like this: `'((start_on <= :start_on AND end_on >= :end_on) OR (start_on <= :start_on AND end_on <= :end_on ...)`

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax (one of several options) is:

```
person.activities_people.where(date: date)
```

Comment: your code throws no result. But if I check for current person `person.activities_people.where(person_id: 2)` are 2 activities_people with same date...